# ASP.Net Core 2.2 - separate serializer settings for input and output

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-2.2

ASP.Net Core 2.2 allows to set serializer settings using `MvcJsonOptions.SerializerSettings` property. The problem is that it affects both input and output. Is there a way to have separate options for input (deserialization) and output (serialization)? In particular, I need to set a different behavior for `NullValueHandling` settings: ignore null errors for non-nullable fields when deserializing client json but keep nulls for defined model fields when serializing the result.

For example, I have a C# model for request:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And input JSON: `{ id: null, parentId: null, name: "test" }`. The deserialization fails for `NullValueHandling.Include` but works for `NullValueHandling.Ignore`.

But when I serialize an entity like this one

```
new SomeEntity
{
    Id = 1,
    ParentId = null,
    Name = "test"
}
```

It keeps null with `NullValueHandling.Include`: `{ id: 1, parentId: null, name: "test" }` but erases it with `NullValueHandling.Ignore`: `{ id: 1, name: "test" }`.

I need to achieve the "Ignore" scenario for input and "Include" for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this workaround: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4562#issuecomment-226100352

```
public class CustomSerializerSettingsSetup : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private readonly ArrayPool<char> _charPool;
    private readonly ObjectPoolProvider _objectPoolProvider;

    public CustomSerializerSettingsSetup(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        ArrayPool<char> charPool,
        ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        _charPool = charPool;
        _objectPoolProvider = objectPoolProvider;
    }

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();
        options.InputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonInputFormatter>();
        options.InputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonPatchInputFormatter>();

        var outputSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new JsonOutputFormatter(outputSettings, _charPool));

        var inputSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        var jsonInputLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<JsonInputFormatter>();
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new JsonInputFormatter(
            jsonInputLogger,
            inputSettings,
            _charPool,
            _objectPoolProvider));

        var jsonInputPatchLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<JsonPatchInputFormatter>();
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new JsonPatchInputFormatter(
            jsonInputPatchLogger,
            inputSettings,
            _charPool,
            _objectPoolProvider));
    }
}
```

and

```
services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, CustomSerializerSettingsSetup>());
```

in service provider configuration

Answer (score -1):

I would use JsonSerializerSettings class from Newtonsoft.Json to define two instances `mySerializeSetting` and `myDeserializeSettings`.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Rest.Serialization;

string requestContent = SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, mySerializationSettings);
```

To deserialize:

```
var result = SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myclass>(input, myDeserializeSettings);
```

To see how to set up serialization settings see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm

Comment: I know how to handle it with Newtonsoft.Json. The question is how to provide different settings for ASP.Net Core 2.2