# how to allow null values during serialization and not allow null values in de-serialization in json.net 12.0

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, json-deserialization, asp.net-core-2.2, nsjsonserialization

Recently we migrated from asp.net to aspnet.core, we've a global setting 
`jsonSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;` 
in StartUp.cs in our Asp.net core project.

This setting doesn't allow nulls during serialization and de-serialization process, as per our requirement we need to allow nulls during de-serialization but doesn't need to allow nulls during serialization i.e. from api response to front-end. How the `NullValueHandling.Ignore` could be override only for serialization process.

Please suggest !

Comment: Which version of asp.net-core are you using?  In [tag:asp.net-core-3.0] Json.NET has become an optional add-on, see [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182), so the answer will be different than in previous versions.

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNetCore" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29660550/7775908)

Comment: Then does this answer your question?  [ASP.Net Core 2.2 - separate serializer settings for input and output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59107392/3744182).